# Regex - Add a word after every X sentences

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I need to insert a word after every X (i.e. 4,5,6 etc) sentences in given text. I feel regex would be compact and good solution. To be specific, I need to do this in .net.

Thanks,

Mihir

(If regex can't identify some sentences ending with not so common punctuation, I am fine with it. I don't need 100% accuracy)

Comment: I don't think regexes are good at identifying sentences: think of all of the edge cases like acronyms. In fact, identifying sentences is rather non-trivial. Only use regexes here if you do not need 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it with the Regex in .NET if you find a match and loop through the string as long as you find new matches. Of course this is no regex-only implementation:

```
string word = "WORD"; // Your word
string sentence = "1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 10."; // Your sentence
long count = 0;
int xSentence = 3; // Numbers of sentence
int pos = 0;

// Your Regex
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[\.,\!,\?]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match mat = reg.Match(sentence);

// While there is a new match
while (mat.Success)
{
    count++;
    if (count % xSentence == 0)
    {
        // +1 to insert the word after punctuation
        pos = mat.Index + 1;

        sentence = sentence.Insert(pos, word);
        mat = reg.Match(sentence, pos);
    }
    else
    {
        mat = mat.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

Maybe this woul help you implementing it in .NET although there are several other ways to do it.

Comment: This is C# code, but you can convert it to VB.NET if you can use it for your code.

Comment: thnx. I made some modification and it turned out just as I wanted, insert some word after X sentence, where X is random number between 4 to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Extended regular expression support the word [boundary operator \b](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).  It can be used to match the end of a sentence. Try this regular expression:

```
((?:\.[^.]+){2})\b(\.)([ \n])
```

This is an example for 2 and 3:

```
$ echo "A. B. C. D. E. F."|perl -wne 's/((?:\.[^.]+){1})\b(\.)([ \n])/$1$2word$3/g && print'
A. B.word C. D.word E. F.word
$ echo "A. B. C. D. E. F."|perl -wne 's/((?:\.[^.]+){2})\b(\.)([ \n])/$1$2word$3/g && print'
A. B. C.word D. E. F.word
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would do a string.Split(".") this will give you an array with each element in the array containing a sentence.  Now you can add the word onto the end of what ever sentences you need. Now you can use String.Join to join the strings together.  Note: don't forget to add the "." back in when joining

Comment: I agree that this is not a place for REGEX. You must be careful however for acronyms like U.S.A. or S.O.S. I suggest iterating over the entire string only counting periods that lie greater than a few characters from one another.